Can AcquireWriterLock in ReaderWriterLock class be used instead of regular Lock (lock() {}) in C#?
Can AcquireWriterLock method in ReaderWriterLock class be used instead of regular Lock ( lock() {} ) in C#?
It seems both are exclusive locks.
lock (object) {  
  // do something  
}

vs
readerWriterLock.AcquireWriterLock();  
  // do something  
readerWriterLock.ReleaseWriterLock();


Sure, that's fine (although ReaderWriterLockSlim may be preferable); however keep in mind "exceptions", i.e. you might want to use try/finally here:
readerWriterLock.AcquireWriterLock();  
try
{
    // do something  
}
finally
{
    readerWriterLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
}

so that you release the lock both in failure and success.
If you need async support: SemaphoreSlim might be a reasonable choice, with the WaitAsync API.
